# Synchronized method in Asystask. Asyntask is not thread, is it?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

When I click a button a call asynctask. In Doinbackgournd of Asysnctask I call a Synchronized method. So will second AsynsT start when first complete the Synchronized method if I click button many times.

Comment: doInBackground is asynchronously called means new thread is created, so second async may start on same time

Comment: but doInBackground call Synchronized menthod. So doInBackground1 complete then doInBackground2 start? Is that right?

Comment: yes doinback...will call synchrobized method but it is nerver sure that ur second thread which is in ur syncronized method will call after the first thread instead u can start that second thread from post execute in ur asynctask

Answer (score 0):

Always new threads will be created when you click button but only one thread will be executing Synchronized method and rest will be kept waiting.

Comment: Thanks. But I use AsyncT not Thread. Is it  Synchronized with AsyncTask.

Comment: AsyncTask is also thread which runs in background. but it is designed specifically to work with GUI

Comment: onPreExecute - runs in background provide access to GUI doInBackground - runs in background do not provide access to GUI onProgressUpdate - publishProgress() is called from do in background to access GUI from doInBackground PostExecute- runs in background after doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

yes doinback...will call synchronized method but it is nerver sure that ur second thread which is in ur syncronized method will call after the first thread instead u can start that second thread from post execute in ur asynctask 
For more details refer this [Api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

You can also use  getStatus() method that tell u that is that aync task running , finished etc.